# Delete Record Using eventname instead of ID

Tags: php, mysql

i am currently creating a web page to delete data from a table using php by using name column in the table instead of ID. But it is not getting deleted when i give the input as event name.

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "database_admin";
    $password = "Veritasirum123";enter code here
    $dbname = "workflow";
    // Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    } 
    ?>


            <?php

            if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
                $ename=$_POST["ename"];
            $sql="DELETE from event where ename=$ename";



    if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
       echo '<script language="javascript">';
        echo 'alert("Event Deleted Successfully")';
        echo '</script>';
    } else {
        echo '<script language="javascript">';
        echo 'alert("Event Deletion Failed")';
        echo '</script>';
    }
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: Try enclosing $ename in single quotes like this '$ename'?

Comment: Is it actually another column? Rather than outputting `Failed` use error reporting http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php. You also are open to SQL injections, use a white list if that really is a column name you are comparing against

Comment: @PushpeshKumarRajwanshi Not if it is a column name

Comment: you check the `$_POST['ename']` is correct with database ename

Comment: @user3783243: I thought ename was column name not $ename.

Answer (score 0):

please check 
this variable value  :$ename=$_POST["ename"];
or 
try using this variable :
$ename=$_GET["ename"];

or 
please past event name static and check it

Answer (score 0):

It can be a issue with the value you are parsing.. or can be a issue with datatype.. check your passing value and remove it's any white spaces by using trim() funcion

$ename=trim($_POST["ename"]);

then if ename field is string then you have to put single quotes. like below

$sql="DELETE from event where ename='$ename'";